# DocuSign Redirect URI not matching or registered properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docusignapi

I seem to be having an error with my DocuSign Redirect URI. It seems to be not registered properly on login.

Error: "The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign".

`https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?client_id=xxxx&scope=signature&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44347%2Fds%2Fcallback&state=xxxx`

I've tried added to the an AccountController the URI with no avail.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "http://localhost:8080/ds/callback")
        {
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = 
            returnUrl });
        }
```

Without the redirect URI:

```
 [Route("ds/[action]")]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = "/")
        {
            return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = returnUrl });
        }

        public IActionResult MustAuthenticate()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IActionResult> logout()
        {
            await AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync(HttpContext);
            return LocalRedirect("/");
        }
    }
```

I expected to be redirected back to the application for a signature.

Comment: This [DocuSign Support Article](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/Redirect-URI-not-registered) may help. Make sure you have it registered in your admin portal and try again. Also, check your URI because you are passing `https://localhost` and I think it should be normal `http://...`

Comment: One thing that is easily confused: `AuthenticationProperties.RedirectUri` is *not* the same as the redirect URI that needs to be registered with the provider (Docusign). Inbar's answer below is correct.

Comment: Any suggestions for creating redirect uri without localhost, I'm using a test app at the moment, maybe I will need one for production.

Comment: you can use cloud service like Azure or AWS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your DocuSign Sandbox Account. Got to DocuSign Admin from top-right menu.
then on the left menu find the "API and Keys" page
find your Integration Key.
Add the "https://localhost:44347/ds/callback" in the list of URLs.
Wait 30 seconds
Try again

(the issue was the port was different for you, maybe cause you use IIS Express?)

Comment: That worked thanks! I am working with test app that is using localhost, am not sure how to create a custom Redirect URI yet.

Comment: glad to help. let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Don't know if you have any input on this but it looks like the page for signing complete is not being found, the following URL was attempted after I do signing: https://localhost:44347//dsReturn?state=123&event=signing_complete

Comment: Nevermind, there was an extra / after the port number